# What's the standard height for an outlet?

Tags: electrical, outlets

I am installing outlets in my patio room.  What is the standard height recommended above the ground for these to be installed?

Comment: While there *is* a "standard height" between 12" and 18" to center (or 16" to the top), I would measure your existing outlets and match them.

Comment: I'd also think about even higher. If I ever build a house, I think most will be a waist/desk height. Just seems odd to always be bending over to plug/unplug everything. ;)

Comment: Lower makes sense for items on the floor, like floor lamps and old cabinet televisions. Today, we're charging phones and laptops on tables.

Comment: The standards are designed for the "living room" situation. they have provisions for plugs above counters like in the kitchen as well.  per standard every 6' along a wall there should be an outlet unless there is a door and or surface area of the wall is less then 3' I believe. I would have to dig up my rule book to be sure though. afci just got added to the list of requirements to due to pets chewing on power cords etc.

Comment: I thought it was 18" standard height for outlets

Comment: It only matters if you have to comply with [ADA code](http://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=90831).

Answer (score 16):

The direct answer to your question is "There is no standard". Outlets can be installed at whatever height is comfortable for the intended use.  The only NEC requirement is that you must be within 6 feet of an outlet along any wall (12' between outlets, A unbroken wall space of 2 feet or more including space measured around a corner requires an outlet. ref. NEC 210.52.A.2. A common height for a wall outlet is between 12 to 16 inches to the bottom of the device. In rare instances, outlets are still installed in baseboards and in the floor with proper box/covers.

Comment: Floor outlets suck. The covers are often broken or lost, so they fill with dirt. A plugged-in cable will get pinched / badly worn by traffic. But if you need 'em, you need 'em. Ceiling outlets are sometimes an option, too.

Comment: (My space is a 30'-diameter room, so I'm never close enough to an outlet!)

Comment: floor outlets are ok when they have a metal cover and are recessed but usually end up being a pain as you said.  celing outlets are awesome as are using builtin spaces like cabinates etc.

Comment: interesting.. I had my new room built onto my house 2 years ago to code and the inspectors said no problem if the outlets were underneath the windows.

Comment: @shirlock homes, I realize this is a couple of years old now, but there are a couple of issues with your answer. The code reads "so that no point along a wall is no farther than 6' from a receptacle", NOT 8'. So receptacles can be 12' apart. Also, there is NO such prohibition for receptacles under windows. Never has been.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey: I agree with everything you said, but I did a home project about 5 years ago and the code stated there needed to be an outlet every 6 feet. I built a 170 sq ft room and there were about 6 outlets in that room. Two were under the windows. This was required by the architect, engineer, and the city code enforcement. I am in Florida. There was not twelve feet between outlets. Also, the electrician who did the work said convention states to stand a hammer on end and that's the height they are placed. He was also old, so maybe that's why he used the hammer.

Comment: @staticx, Well, I'd be curious to see that in writing. I have never in all my years heard of any location having that extreme of a code amendment (ie: doubling the amount of required receptacles). I'd bet money that everyone involved was simply mistaken in their interpretation of this section of the code. It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey: I'd show you my blue prints if I could

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt that someone said it is required. Especially an architect.

Answer (score 6):

When I had my new room built onto my house, the electrician used a standard claw hammer for the height. The electrician stated that this is a general rule of thumb that many electricians use. In fact, a simple google search revealed that someone at the [DoItYourself.com](http://www.doityourself.com/forum/electrical-c-d-c/59969-electrical-outlet-height.html) forums, recommended a standard 16 oz hammer standing on its end as a reference height. The eHow.com site recommends using an ["electrician's hammer"](http://www.ehow.com/facts_7555009_height-outlet-boxes-basement.html) as the point of reference. A forum post a the [DIYChatroom](http://www.diychatroom.com/f18/minimum-outlet-height-17824/) recommends also to use a 16 oz hammer that gets you about 18 inches off the floor.

So, I would use the hammer as a guide.

Comment: I thought "electrician's hammer" was an alternate term for lineman's pliers.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Nope: http://www.tools-plus.com/klein-807-18.html

Comment: "Hammer height" is an OLD electrician's trick for new work. In old work/renovation typically we just match any existing ones. I haven't seen anyone use hammer height in years.

Comment: A 'standard' hammer does not exist. Many different manufacturers make hammers, each to their own design. The method does however, ensure uniformity throughout the job, so there is some merit in that. Otherwise, use a tape measure, it's what they are for...

Answer (score 6):

In the UK, [Part P of the Building Regulations 2010](https://www.specifiedby.com/building-regulations/approved-document-p-electrical-safety#Section1) states that for new builds (**emphasis** mine):

> [Approved Document M](https://www.specifiedby.com/building-regulations/approved-document-m-access-use-buildings#Section8) recommends that in new dwellings only, **switches and socket-outlets for lighting and other equipment should be between 450mm and 1200mm from finished floor level**. Approved Document M does not recommend a height for new consumer units. However, one way of complying with Part M in new dwellings is to mount consumer units so that the switches are between 1350mm and 1450mm above floor level. At this height, the consumer unit is out of reach of young children yet accessible to other people when standing or sitting.

In practice, in areas where there is limited risk, it tends to be the case that unless otherwise specified, a home builder will install light switches at 1.2m above finished floor level, and sockets are at 450mm (approx 18inches) above finished floor level. Isolating switches such as those for a extractor fan for a shower are exempt from those heights (and instead would be installed close to the ceiling level).

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with @matthew because it answers your question of, “What is the standard heigh...?”, and I like matching the height of the existing outlets.

However, more and more of the homes we are doing we install outlets 18” AFF to match ADA requirements (not because we have to, but because the clients are older and acknowledge their “reach range” is decreasing).

We are also installing elevators (or shafts for future elevators) in multi story houses too. As the population ages, we’ll all be thinking about designing “things” and “uses” for this aging group.

Comment: is that 18" to the bottom, center, or top of the outlet?

Comment: @DavidDoria I just checked with ANSI requirements and their new requirements are 15” to the bottom of outlets, drawers, etc. for unobstructed reach. That is to say, not reaching over or under anything. (See ANSI 308.)

Answer (score 2):

A hammer length or the front part of a spade is good rough approximation. The exact answer according to the code of practice [SANS 10142](http://www.scribd.com/doc/32614384/SANS-10142-1-2009-Edition-1-7-the-Wiring-of-Premises-LV-Installations) states that it must be 500 mm above floor level.

Comment: In what world is this code???

Comment: A link to the code referenced would be useful.

Comment: Google says it's the South African code.  The most recent complete document I was able to find is from [2009](http://www.scribd.com/doc/32614384/SANS-10142-1-2009-Edition-1-7-the-Wiring-of-Premises-LV-Installations); but Google shows several amendments published since.

Answer (score 1):

There is no code on the height of  electrical outlets. You have a standard height of 16" to the top of the outlet box, and a standard height of 48" to the top of the switch box. Then, there are custom heights in which different company use accordingly to the home owner or builder. Spec homes generally get standard height, and custom homes usually get standard height as well, unless other wise specified by the blue print, home owner or builder.

Answer (score 0):

13" or hammer length above sub floor to bottom of box (Not a framing hammer) that's it. It is in the nec code book and there is a standard in there for all outlets. Kitchen, utility room, bath etc: .

Comment: Can you give a specific Code cite for this?

Answer (score 0):

wiring for myself all my kitchen outlet's are above counter height. I have outlets at 6 feet behind tvs, an outlet at bed height beside my bed for convenience (mine). 42" height by my desk. make your own conditions