# How high should I install an outlet in my bathroom?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I would like to install a GFCI outlet in my bathroom. I attempted to install it beside our vanity mirror on first the left then the right side, but was unable to due to the construction of the wall, where the studs where placed too closely together. So, I decided to place the outlet on the wall opposite of the sink. My question is, how high from the floor should I place this outlet?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to install a new receptacle in a wall, or are you converting an existing receptacle to GFCI?

Comment: I am installing a new receptacle. This bathroom did not have any receptacles when we purchased the home.

Comment: Reason I ask is 99% of GFCI questions relate to the difference, so GFCI in the title tends to draw people good at solving those problems.   In your case it's entirely a construction question...

Comment: So it doesn't matter how high off the floor? I was worried that the typical 16 inches was not high enough for a bathroom.

Comment: To be clearer, your title is confusing as to whether you are upgrading to GFCI.   I would suggest simply removing "GFCI" from the title. I don't know the answer to your question, but the edit I suggest will help draw construction folks instead of electrical folks like me.

Comment: Related, but I guess since it's possible in a "wet" location, not a direct duplicate: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/17001/43874

Comment: Thanks, Harper. It seems like this is a preference. I might go higher than usual on this one. Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem that you can't fit a box where you wanted, or that you can't get the wires to the location? Studs being in the way shouldn't stop you from installing the outlet where you want it.

Comment: If you have a built in medicine cabinet there may be several studs right at that location but another 1-1/2" over there is probably space.

Comment: somewhere between standing wrist and elbow height, to allow easy hand appliances plugging.

Comment: The studs on the vanity side of the bathroom are just about 3 inches apart all the way across the wall and not a single one of them have nails/screws in them. I couldn't locate them using my magnet and the thud on the wall sounded hollow until I poked a few holes only to find these have studs behind them too close to place the receptacle box. I could notch out a spot, but I decided to use the adjacent wall. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a wall there is not a minimum or maximum height. The question would be how high would you like it? If close to the basin they are usually placed several inches above the counter space but again no code height restriction on the walls. The one thing is it can not be placed in a wet location like above a tub unless outside the tub zone.